# How to retain value and compute based on group of first month purchase the next amount of purchase in sql

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, retention

i would like to create customer retention.

So i've this table :

| id | date | purchase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01 | 200 |
| 2 | 2020-12 | 100 |
| 2 | 2020-03 | 150 |
| 3 | 2020-03 | 200 |
| 1 | 2020-07 | 120 |
| 1 | 2020-08 | 300 |
| 3 | 2020-05 | 250 |

and i want this output :

| purchase month | first purchase month | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01 | 200 |
| 6 | 2020-01 | 320 |
| 7 | 2020-01 | 620 |
| 0 | 2020-03 | 350 |
| 4 | 2020-03 | 600 |
| 11 | 2020-03 | 700 |

"Customers who placed their first order in Jan 2020 spent 200 in month 0 (so in Jan 2020) and 120 (320-200) in month 6 (so in Jul 2020)."

"Customers who placed their first order in Mar 2020 spent 350 in month 0 (so Mar 2020) and 250 (600-350) in month 4 (so May 2020)."

Thanks by advance for your help

Comment: Please keep in mind that `jQuery` and `Query` is not the same when you select tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with window function and common table expression.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table purchases(id int, date date, purchase int);
 insert into purchases values(1,    '2020-01',  200);
 insert into purchases values(2,    '2020-12',  100);
 insert into purchases values(2,    '2020-03',  150);
 insert into purchases values(3,    '2020-03',  200);
 insert into purchases values(1,    '2020-07',  120);
 insert into purchases values(1,    '2020-08',  300);
 insert into purchases values(3,    '2020-05',  250);
```

Query:

```
with cte as
     ( 
       select id,date,purchase,
       min(date)over(partition by id) FirstPurchaseMonth from purchases
     )
     ,cte2 as
     (
       select substr(date,6,2)-substr(firstpurchasemonth,6,2) Purchasemonth, max(FirstPurchaseMonth)firstpurchasemonth, 
       purchase,sum(purchase)total from cte
       group by firstpurchasemonth,substr(date,6,2)-substr(firstpurchasemonth,6,2) 
     )
     select purchasemonth,firstpurchasemonth,sum(total)over(partition by firstpurchasemonth order by purchasemonth)total
     from cte2
```

Output:

| Purchasemonth | firstpurchasemonth | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01 | 200 |
| 6 | 2020-01 | 320 |
| 7 | 2020-01 | 620 |
| 0 | 2020-03 | 350 |
| 2 | 2020-03 | 600 |
| 9 | 2020-03 | 700 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5525a087751b2f3923cee3de2c35253d)*